# Добавление материалов

Tags: html

Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог сам добавлять статью на аш сайт?

Comment: Сёма, не парься ты так :) ... может просто тебе CMS (системку управления сайтом) порекомендовать? Там такие действия есть!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не правильная метка :) надо php - если вы про собственный само написанный сайт сайт. Да если и не сами всё ровно другая метка должна быть.

Что Вам нужно ?

1. MySql
2. PHP
3. HTML Формочка

Создаём базу к примеру "Site"
И делаем таблицу "text" с полями:

- idText INT  255  PRIMARY A__I(или Auto_Increment)
- Title VARCHAR 45
- Text TEXT

Создаём файлик например - add.php
Потом подключаем его к базе
В самом верху файлика

```
 $ConnectBd = mysql_connect ("Хост - обычно Localhost","Логин к БД", "Пароль к Бд");
 mysql_select_db ("Название Бд",$ConnectBd);
 if (isset($_POST['Title']))       
 {
    $Title = $_POST['Title'];

 if ($Title == '') 
 {
 unset($Title);
 }

 }

 if (isset($_POST['Text'])) {$Text = $_POST['Text']; if ($Text == '') {unset($Text);}}

 $add = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO text (Title,Text) VALUES ('$Title','$Text')");
```

БД* - База Данных

Создаём Файл - например formadd.php
Делаем  в нём формочку:

```
<form action='add.php' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='Title' />
<textarea cols='10' rows='10' name='Text'>
<input name="go" type="submit">
</form>
```

Потом заходи в форму и забивай поля - и если всё правильно сделали то добавиться текст в базу. 
Вывод текста :

Создаём Файлик get.php

И там пишем

```
  $Get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM text ORDER BY idText DESC ",$ConnectBd);
  $GetText = mysql_fetch_array($Get);

  While($GetText = mysql_fetch_array($Get)){

   echo $GetText['Title']; 
   echo '<br />' . $GetText['Text'];
   }
```

Всё вроде. Удачи. (Это упрощённый вариант - можно ещё куча сделать проверок , полей и легче сделать скрипт. Могу написать если очень нужно.)
Возможно где то есть ошибки - писал на скорую  руку , если есть поправьте пожалуйста.

Comment: ну и зачем было так расспинтся?:)<br> и вам бы почитать о разделении логики вывода от бизнес логики...<br>А в проверках надо было писать не `if($text=='')` а `if(is_string($text))`<br>
<small><i>и вообще код ужасен...</i></small>

Comment: Для новичка Код Хорош и прост, зачем сразу учить заумно хитрыми фишками и отделения логики от дизайна,мозг не вынесет.

Comment: за плюсиГ :) 
Я не распинался...я статью переделал под этот случай - кое что убрал - что то подставил. Я бы такое не когда просто так сам не написал - мне лень :).

Answer (score 0):

Визивиг редактор, ну и форма с необходимыми полями, которая скидывает статью в базу. Желательно сделать поле в базе что-то типа "moderation" 0 по умолчанию, админ смотрит статью, ставит 1 и статья отображается. )

Answer (score 0):

Назначить его в группу у которой есть права публиковать статьи.

П.С. По "воздушному" вопросу, тыкнул пальцем в небо за ответом, но для общего случая мой ответ подойдет. Подробнее хотите, пишите подробный вопрос, с версиями, движками, проблемами, и т.д.